# PHP for loop return single value

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, return-value

I want to make the for loop to return a single value (TRUE/FALSE). But the code returns multiple value. Like TRUETRUETRUE. I understand the code but didn't have any idea to do it.

```
public function user_activation_check(){
    for($i=1;$i<5;$i++){
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT group_info.member".$i." FROM `group_info` INNER JOIN `user_student` ON group_info.member$i=user_student.email WHERE user_student.email=group_info.member$i");
        if($query->num_rows()==1){
            //return TRUE;
            echo"true";
        }else {
            //return FALSE;
            echo"false";
        }
    }
}
```

Help please.

UPDATE:

```
public function member_activation(){
    if($this->model_users->user_activation_check()){
        $this->load->view('v_confirm_group');
    }else echo "Some members didn't activate their account.";
}
```

Comment: I uhh, I don't see how it can return multiple values. Simply not right. Is this your entire code?

Comment: A function only returns one value each time it is called...

Comment: then why u use for loop?

Comment: can you post complete function?

Comment: sorry for not posting the full code. this is the full code.

Comment: You're writing out a string, not returning it from your function. See this page for an explanation of the PHP return statement: http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
public function user_activation_check(){
   for($i=1;$i<5;$i++){
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT group_info.member".$i." FROM `group_info` INNER JOIN `user_student` ON group_info.member$i=user_student.email WHERE user_student.email=group_info.member$i");
        if($query->num_rows()==1){
            // do nothing
        }else {
            echo "false"; // *atleast* one member didn't.
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    echo "true";
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Thx man! Simple solution! It works! Exactly what i want.

Answer (score 4):

use array same as:

```
     $res = array():
for($i=1;$i<5;$i++){
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT group_........");
    if($query->num_rows()==1){
        $res[] = TRUE;
    }else {
        $res[] =  FALSE;
    }
}
return $res;
```

Comment: thx for the answer. but thats not what i want to achieve. i just want it to return TRUE/FALSE. Not return an array. Still trying to find a  solution.

Answer (score 0):

It echoes multiple values, because your running a loop. It will echo five values, one for each excecution of the loop. If you only want it to echo once, use `return`. A function can echo multiple times, however it can only return one value. When it returned true or false, it ends the excecution of the function.